# Configure Zopim chat window to link to custom page

Tags: javascript, livechat

Does anyone know how I can edit the Zopim chat code on my company site, using the Zopim API, to force Zopim to not open the chat window when clicked and instead open a custom page when clicked?

For example: We want it so that when our support team is offline in Zopim if a customer clicks the visible chat widget it opens http://oursite.com and customers are not offered the chance to leave a Zopim offline message.

How can we do this?

Many thanks - Ian

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the following:
1) Hide when offline
2) Copy the image of the offline Zopim button
3) Paste it exactly on the same spot with custom link
4) Make it z-index 10000 (just below 14001 which Zopim uses)